# Looking for file of Sfard kedushah page for Ashkenaz siddurim

Tags: prayer-book

I daven nusach Ashkenaz in a shul which davens nusach Sfard. On Shabbos, it's customary* to say the "out loud" parts of the davening in the minhag hamakom. Therefore, in the back cover of the Ashkenaz siddurim, we have a page pasted in that has the Sfard kedusah (both for Shacharis and Musaf), so you can turn there during the Kedushah. The bottom of it says something to the effect of "Copyright attributable to ArtScroll, reproduced with permission".

Not all siddurim in our shul have it, so I'm looking for a file I can print out a few copies and glue them in myself. At worse, I can always scan in a siddur that has it, but they're old and the copy would be somewhat degraded. Does anyone have a copy of this file?

*It may actually be halacha, I can't cite a source either way, perhaps someone else can?

Edit: Here's a photo of the page. I contacted ArtScroll to see if they have a copy they can send me. I confirmed that it was not created by anyone at our shul.
[image: Sfard Kedushah Page]

Comment: All the parts of kedusha a congregant needs to say are the same across all traditions, so this really shouldn't be 
strictly necessary.

Comment: If you include a picture of it that might help people figure something out for you.

Comment: I've added a picture. Did you delete my response to your first comment about the congregant responses being the same? I certainly didn't delete it.

Answer (score 1):

I have copied the Shabbat kedushas from Sefaria below and hope that will suffice:

> Shabbat Morning בחזרת הש"ץ: אומרים קדושה
>
> נַקְדִּישָׁךְ וְנַעֲרִיצָךְ כְּנֹעַם שִׂיחַ סוֹד שַׂרְפֵי קֹדֶשׁ.
>   הַמְּשַׁלְּשִׁים לְךָ קְדֻשָּׁה. כַּכָּתוּב עַל יַד נְבִיאֶךָ. וְקָרָא
>   זֶה אֶל זֶה וְאָמַר:
>
> קו"ח: קָדוֹשׁ קָדוֹשׁ קָדוֹשׁ יְהֹוָה צְבָאוֹת. מְלֹא כָל הָאָרֶץ
>   כְּבוֹדוֹ:  חזן: אָז. בְּקוֹל רַעַשׁ גָּדוֹל אַדִּיר וְחָזָק.
>   מַשְׁמִיעִים קוֹל. מִתְנַשְּׂאִים לְעֻמַּת שְׂרָפִים. לְעֻמָּתָם
>   מְשַׁבְּחִים וְאוֹמְרִים:
>
> קו"ח: בָּרוּךְ כְּבוֹד יְהֹוָה מִמְּקוֹמוֹ: חזן: מִמְּקוֹמְךָ
>   מַלְכֵּנוּ תוֹפִיעַ. וְתִמְלוֹךְ עָלֵינוּ  (מְהֵרָה)  כִּי מְחַכִּים
>   אֲנַחְנוּ לָךְ. מָתַי תִּמְלֹךְ בְּצִיּוֹן. בְּקָרוֹב בְּיָמֵינוּ
>   לְעוֹלָם וָעֶד תִּשְׁכּוֹן. תִּתְגַּדֵּל וְתִתְקַדֵּשׁ בְּתוֹךְ
>   יְרוּשָׁלַיִם עִירְךָ לְדוֹר וָדוֹר וּלְנֵצַח  נְצָחִים. וְעֵינֵינוּ
>   תִרְאֶינָה מַלְכוּתֶךָ כַּדָּבָר הָאָמוּר בְּשִׁירֵי עֻזֶּךָ. עַל
>   יְדֵי דָּוִד מְשִׁיחַ צִדְקֶךָ:
>
> קו"ח: יִמְלֹךְ יְהֹוָה לְעוֹלָם. אֱלֹהַיִךְ צִיּוֹן לְדֹר וָדֹר.
>   הַלְלוּיָהּ:
>
> אַתָּה קָדוֹשׁ, וְשִׁמְךָ קָדוֹשׁ, וּקְדוֹשִׁים בְּכָל יוֹם
>   יְהַלְלוּךָ סֶּלָה. כִּי אֵל מֶלֶךְ גָדוֹל וְקָדוֹשׁ אָתָּה. בָּרוּךְ
>   אַתָּה יְהֹוָה, הָאֵל  (בעשרת ימי תשובה: הַמֶּלֶךְ)  הַקָּדוֹשׁ:
>
> Musaf בחזרת הש"ץ אומרים כתר:
>
> כֶּתֶר יִתְּנוּ לְךָ, יְהֹוָה אֱלֹהֵינוּ מַלְאָכִים הֲמוֹנֵי
>   מַעְלָה. עִם עַמְּךָ יִשְׂרָאֵל קְבוּצֵי מַטָּה: יַחַד כֻּלָּם
>   קְדֻשָּׁה לְךָ יְשַׁלֵּשׁוּ כַּדָּבָר הָאָמוּר עַל יַד נְבִיאֶךָ
>   וְקָרָא זֶה אֶל זֶה וְאָמַר:
>
> קו"ח: קָדוֹשׁ קָדוֹשׁ קָדוֹשׁ יְהֹוָה צְבָאוֹת מְלֹא כָל הָאָרֶץ
>   כְּבוֹדוֹ:  חזן: כְּבוֹדוֹ מָלֵא עוֹלָם. מְשָׁרְתָיו שׁוֹאֲלִים זֶה
>   לָזֶה אַיֵּה מְקוֹם כְּבוֹדוֹ לְהַעֲרִיצוֹ. לְעֻמָּתָם מְשַׁבְּחִים
>   וְאוֹמְרִים:
>
> קו"ח: בָּרוּךְ כְּבוֹד יְהֹוָה מִמְּקוֹמוֹ: חזן: מִמְּקוֹמוֹ הוּא
>   יִפֶן בְּרַחֲמָיו לְעַמּוֹ. וְיָחוֹן עַם הַמְיַחֲדִים שְׁמוֹ עֶרֶב
>   וָבוֹקֶר בְּכָל יוֹם תָּמִיד. פַּעֲמַיִם בְּאַהֲבָה שְׁמַע אוֹמְרִים:
>
> קו"ח: שְׁמַע יִשְׂרָאֵל יְהֹוָה אֱלֹהֵינוּ יְהֹוָה אֶחָד: חזן: הוּא
>   אֱלֹהֵינוּ הוּא אָבִינוּ. הוּא מַלְכֵּנוּ הוּא מוֹשִׁיעֵנוּ. וְהוּא
>   יוֹשִׁיעֵנוּ וְיִגְאָלֵנוּ שֵׁנִית וְיַשְׁמִיעֵנוּ בְּרַחֲמָיו שֵׁנִית
>   לְעֵינֵי כָּל חַי לֵאמֹר. הֵן גָּאַלְתִּי אֶתְכֶם אַחֲרִית כְּרֵאשִׁית
>   לִהְיוֹת לָכֶם לֵאלֹהִים:
>
> קו"ח: אֲנִי יְהֹוָה אֱלֹהֵיכֶם: חזן: וּבְדִבְרֵי קָדְשְׁךָ כָּתוּב
>   לֵאמֹר: קו"ח: יִמְלֹךְ יְהֹוָה לְעוֹלָם. אֱלֹהַיִךְ צִיּוֹן לְדֹר
>   וָדֹר. הַלְלוּיָהּ:
>
> חזן:לְדוֹר וָדוֹר נַגִּיד גָּדְלֶךָ. וּלְנֵצַח נְצָחִים קְדֻשָּׁתְךָ
>   נַקְדִּישׁ. וְשִׁבְחֲךָ אֱלֹהֵינוּ מִפִּינוּ לֹא יָמוּשׁ לְעוֹלָם
>   וָעֶד. כִּי אֵל מֶלֶךְ גָּדוֹל וְקָדוֹשׁ אָתָּה: בָּרוּךְ אַתָּה
>   יְהֹוָה. הָאֵל (בשבת שובה הַמֶּלֶךְ) הַקָּדוֹשׁ:
>
> Shabbat Mincha בחזרת הש"ץ: אומרים קדושה
>
> נַקְדִּישָׁךְ וְנַעֲרִיצָךְ כְּנֹעַם שִׂיחַ סוֹד שַׂרְפֵי קֹדֶשׁ,
>   הַמְשַׁלְּשִׁים לְךָ קְדֻשָּׁה. כַּכָּתוּב עַל יַד נְבִיאֶךָ: וְקָרָא
>   זֶה אֶל זֶה וְאָמַר:
>
> קָדוֹש, קָדוֹש, קָדוֹש, יְהֹוָה צְבָאוֹת. מְלֹא כָל הָאָרֶץ
>   כְּבוֹדוֹ. לְעֻמָּתָם מְשַׁבְּחִים וְאוֹמְרִים:
>
> בָּרוּךְ כְּבוֹד יְהֹוָה מִמְּקוֹמוֹ. וּבְדִבְרֵי קָדְשְׁךָ כָּתוּב
>   לֵּאמֹר:  יִמְלֹךְ יְהֹוָה לְעוֹלָם אֱלֹהַיִךְ צִיּוֹן לְדֹר וָדֹר,
>   הַלְלוּיָהּ.
>
> אַתָּה קָדוֹשׁ, וְשִׁמְךָ קָדוֹשׁ, וּקְדוֹשִׁים בְּכָל יוֹם
>   יְהַלְלוּךָ סֶּלָה. כִּי אֵל מֶלֶךְ גָדוֹל וְקָדוֹשׁ אָתָּה. בָּרוּךְ
>   אַתָּה יְהֹוָה, הָאֵל  (בעשרת ימי תשובה: הַמֶּלֶךְ)  הַקָּדוֹשׁ:

Comment: Take care with printing this as it contains the name of Hashem.